# How to edit remote registry via c#

Tags: c#, registry, 64-bit, remote-access, 32-bit

How can I edit a remote registry from 32-bit app to 64-bit server.

It very important: remote registry brunch must be 64bit, not 32bit.

I write code like this:

```
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, remoteServerName)
 .OpenSubKey(SUBKEY,true);

if (key != null)
{
    key.SetValue(KEY_1, Value_1);
    key.Close();
    key.Dispose();
}
```

It runs on 64-bit platform and edit 64bit server registry key.

How to edit the same key(64bit branch) via app runs on 32bit platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an additional argument (`RegistryView.Registry32`) to OpenRemoteBaseKey like the example below.

```
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, remoteServerName, RegistryView.Registry32)
```

These links would be helpful for you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411615(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview(v=vs.110).aspx